# Userscript not working on dynamically loaded iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, dynamic, userscripts

I am trying to create a userscript that will just remove all `spellcheck=false` attributes from all websites. In general, I mostly just care about the wikia visual editor, and that is where I am getting all of my trouble.

You should just be able to `document.querySelectorAll('[spellcheck]');` and have that run on all frames. Except wikia appears to dynamically load their iframe visual editor, as it does not appear in their straight source, and my script only runs once  and finds nothing on that page.

Is there a way to have userscript run on dynamic content/iframes added after the page has fully loaded?

Note: Personally run Chrome and Tampermonkey.

Comment: I think it can be done with `setTimeout` or `setInterval`

Comment: Ah, that probably would do it normally, if we were not talking about iframes.

As it is now, normal `document.querySelectorAll` do not even reach this content when I type it the console.

Comment: Because you can't reach elements of iframe using only `document`. You need to use `contentDocument`, for example: `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentDocument.querySelectorAll('[spellcheck]')`

Comment: It works. But It seems to mess with the loading of some pages, but I bet that it the `setTimeout`.